# Spark 2.3 java udf does it need to be registered in each and every java class in the application?

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Using Spark sql 2.3 java and json file. Not using any db.
 Created a spark java udf in a separate class and trying to call this `udf` from other class via `callUdf`("`udfName`",`col()`) and also registered this `udf` in the same class as it doesn't run if I don't register.
I have 4 other java classes in spark sql `df` query that needs to call this `udf` and I just want to register this `udf` once. Any ideas please.

```
public class testUDF implements UDF1<String, String>, Serializable{
 @Override
    public String call(String value) {
    enter code here}}
```

In the other class where I am having df api query. I am using the following

```
  TestUdf testUdf = new TestUdf();
        spark.sqlContext().udf().register("testUdf", testUdf, DataTypes.StringType);
```

In Query

```
callUDF("testUdf", col("someCol"))
```

**Need to register the udf in every single java df class wherever I need to use callUDf. any suggestions to just register once and use everywhere in the application plz.**

Below is the error if we don't register the `udf` in each and every class thank u.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'testUdf'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.;
```